# Finding element on Mongodb collection array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My usuario collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5817a06de4e150a1418b4567"),  
  "idStore" : [
"58177ca2e4e15041058b4567", 
"5817a192e4e150d7098b4567",         
"5817bbb3e4e15020778b4567"
]}

db.collection('atendimento').aggregate([{ $match: { dataI:{ $gt: fDate },     status: 'OCUPADO' } }, 
            { $group: {_id: {"idLoja":"$idLoja", "venda":"$sim"},  qtd:     {"$sum":1}} },  
             {$sort: {'_id.idLoja': 1, '_id.venda': 1}}]).toArray(function(err,     result) {
            var vIdLoja = '';
            for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {   
                vIdLoja = result[x]._id.idLoja;
.
.
.
    db.collection('usuario').find({idStore: { $elemMatch: { $gte: vIdLoja, $lte: vIdLoja } }}).toArray(function(err, result) {
```

or:

```
db.collection('usuario').find({idStore: vIdLoja}).toArray(function(err, result) {
```

The result is the same: `empty/undefined`
driver: MongoClient

How can I solve that issue?

Comment: if you are not getting any results then it would suggest that the values do not actually match. Possibly the values in `"idStore"` are actually of `Objectid` type. You also commented below that *"
In reality, the vIdLoja content comes from an aggregation query of ids"*. So how is this variable actually defined as opposed to the "string" you have supplied in your question. Show the full code that shows this variable being assigned. Again, the assigned variable no doubt does not contain what you think it does.

Comment: Code added, thanks.

Comment: That has a useless assignment here `vIdLoja = result[x]._id.idLoja;` Because you are just overwriting the value in `vidLoja` on every loop iteration. Did you mean to make an array? What is actually happening is the value will be the **last** result from the aggregation, which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: It's also unclear what the data being returned in `"idLoja"` actually looks like. Perhaps you should `console.log()` the values.

Comment: @neilLunn, that is my intention. The content of vIdLoja it's correct, string of what I'm looking for. But, I don't know why, the second find doesn't return records.

Comment: Where is the second query being run? Is it actually within the callback from the `.aggregate()` method? If not then you have fallen victim to the classic async problem.

Comment: Yes, inside callback. Can I share my 200 lines code with you?

Comment: If it helps. I'm sure you can simply add that to the question. Helpful hint is to highlight your code block and pres Ctrl+K, which will indent it as a code block for posting here.

Comment: Regarding Stackoverflow limitation, Did't let me post all the code here. Another way?

Answer (score 0):

As `idStore` is a simple array of strings, you can just query that field directly:

`db.collection('usuario').find({ idStore: "5817a192e4e150d7098b456" }, ...);`

Comment: In reality, the vIdLoja content comes from an aggregation query of ids.